# apt-mirror is failing to read and use the http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy/Release file

Tags: ubuntu, apt, ubuntu-22.04

I have a problem with apt-mirror.

I am tying to set up an internal Ubuntu mirror for my company.

My company using a Squid Proxy: internal IP 10.###.###.5:3128
Our proxy does not need a user/pass.

I am running Ubuntu.

```
DISTRIB_RELEASE=22.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=jammy
Linux ber-app-29v 6.5.0-21-generi
```

I `apt-get install` works with adding `evn` variables

```
export http_proxy="http://10.###,###.5:3128"
export https_proxy="https://10.###,###.5:3128"
export ftp_proxy="http://10.###,###.5:3128"
```

So I can `sudo apt update`. I have been searching for a solution, and found this page: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1443194/apt-mirror-error/1448476
So added it to the file.

The `/ets/apt/mirror.list`

```
{ ############# config ##################
#
set base_path    /usr/share/nginx/html/repo/Ubuntu

### More commented values

# set run_postmirror 0
set nthreads     20
set _tilde 0

# to access to repo list at http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/
set no_check_certificate 1

# Jammy 22.04
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy main restricted universe multiverse   
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-updates main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-security main restricted universe 
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-backports main restricted universe 

#Focal 20.04
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-updates main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-security main restricted universe 
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-backports main restricted universe 

clean http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu
```

The proxy file `/ets/apt/apt.conf.d/90curtin-aptproxy`

```
# Proxysetting for apt

Acquire::http::Proxy "http://10.###.###.5:3128/";
Acquire::https::Proxy "https://10.###.###.5:3128/";
Acquire::tcp::Proxy "tcp://10.###.###.5:3128/";
```

I have tested with both curl:
`url -v --insecure http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy/Release 1>/dev/null`

```
* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Last-Modified: Thu, 21 Apr 2022 17:16:39 GMT
< Content-Length: 269219
< Date: Thu, 07 Mar 2024 13:10:40 GMT
```

`wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial/Release`

```
--2024-03-07 12:58:17--  http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial/Release Connecting to 10.246.214.5:3128... connected.
Proxy request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 245864 (240K)
Saving to: ‘Release.1’

2024-03-07 12:58:18 (176 MB/s) - ‘Release.1’ saved [245864/245864]
```

`apt-get` itself is working, and `apt update` too.

```
sudo apt-get install mc
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:   
  libssh2-1 mc-data unzip
Suggested packages:
...
Scanning processes...                                                                                                                                           
Scanning linux images...                                                                                                                                        
Running kernel seems to be up-to-date.
No services need to be restarted.
No containers need to be restarted.
No user sessions are running outdated binaries.
No VM guests are running outdated hypervisor (qemu) binaries on this host.
```

But with all of that `apt-mirror` breaks.

```
sudo apt-mirror
Downloading 304 index files using 20 threads...
Begin time: Thu Mar  7 13:44:42 2024
[20]... [19]... [18]... [17]... [16]... [15]... [14]... [13]... [12]... [11]... [10]... [9]... [8]... [7]... [6]... [5]... [4]... [3]... [2]... [1]... [0]... 
End time: Thu Mar  7 13:44:42 2024

  Failed to open Release file from http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy/Release at /usr/bin/apt-mirror line 507.
  Failed to open Release file from http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy/Release at /usr/bin/apt-mirror line 507.
  Failed to open Release file from http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy/Release at /usr/bin/apt-mirror line 507.
  Failed to open Release file from http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy/Release at /usr/bin/apt-mirror line 507.
  ...
  Also for line 653, 800
```

apt-mirror line 507 and 653

```
    unless ( open STREAM, "<$release_path" )
{
    warn( "Failed to open Release file from " . $release_uri );
    return;
}
```

apt-mirror line 800

```
    unless ( open STREAM, "<$path/$index" )
{
    warn("apt-mirror: can't open index $path/$index in process_index");
    return;
}
```

So what is **else** is wrong?  I am running out of ideas to check.
All of the pieces are working as expected, but not the whole (apt-mirror).

Is there another utility or setting I am missing?

Comment: I am looking into `debmirror` as an alternative, but if I can get an solution for apt-mirror then I rather have that.  I don't want to restart my effort with a new utility.

Comment: In general on Linux there is a subset of applications that ignore lower-case proxy environment variables like `http_proxy` and require uppercase `HTTP_PROXY` resp.  `HTTPS_PROXY`

Comment: Nice, I will add that for general use later.  No effect on apt-mirror behavior.

Comment: And IIRC `apt-mirror` runs rsync, so you should probably also set up the `rsync_proxy` and `RSYNC_PROXY=10.###.###.5:3128`  environment vars

Comment: why would you like to use a complete mirror while using only 1% of the packages? apt-cacher-ng which cache frequently requested packages, while it does not waste storage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works now.  I was able to work through my proxy.
The `set` command needs to be included in the proxy settings
Then I was able to mirror Unbutu archive (All 725 GB).

```
# to access to repo list at http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/
set no_check_certificate 1


# adding proxy setting here
set use_proxy   on
set http_proxy  http://10.###.###.5:3128
set https_proxy https://10.###.###.5:3128
set ftp_proxy   http://10.###.###.5:3128
```

It is a long download to perform.  @11 Kbps it took 18 hours to finish
I suspect all of the archive files were fetched (source, and other files I will not need.  I will purge them manually.

Comment: welcome richarde, remind to accept an answer else we will be reminded until the end of the universe, to solve this issue

Answer (score 2):

I'm the author of the [apt-mirror2](https://gitlab.com/apt-mirror2/apt-mirror2).
To use proxy for apt-mirror you should use `mirror.list` configuration:

```
use_proxy             on
## If proxy scheme is ommited, `http://` assumed
http_proxy            http://10.###.###.5:3128
https_proxy           http://10.###.###.5:3128
```

Please note that there are several problems exists in the apt-mirror which were fixed in the apt-mirror2.

Comment: So far so good (downloading packages, as of this comment)
My system is fetch all of Ubuntu's repos.
```use_proxy             on
## If proxy scheme is ommited, http:// assumed
set http_proxy            http://10.###.###.5:3128
set https_proxy           http://10.###.###.5:3128```

Comment: I needed to add .```set http_proxy            http://10.###.###.5:3128``` to set the variable for the apt-mirror, still fetching.

Comment: This answer helped my find my answer.